# React Native Action Bar icon not working for white background

Tags: react-native

I am using "react-native-action-bar" library for my application action bar.

It's showing white icon when I am using dark background and that's fine, But when i am using white background in case icon also showing white.

I tried with different codes but nothing helped, if anyone having solution for the same please let me know...here is my code

```
<ActionBar
          containerStyle={{height:60,alignSelf: 'center',paddingRight:40}}
          backgroundColor={'#fff'}
          title={'My Tutorials'}
          titleStyle={styles.pageTitle}
          onLeftPress={() => goBack()}
          leftIconContainerStyle={{marginTop:22}}
          leftIconName={'back'}
          leftIconImageStyle={{backgroundColor:'#333',height:18,width:18}}
        />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try giving background color to your badgeColor

```
<ActionBar
          containerStyle={{height:60,alignSelf: 'center',paddingRight:40}}
          backgroundColor={'#fff' }
          badgeColor={'#000000'}
          title={'My Tutorials'}
          titleStyle={styles.pageTitle}
          onLeftPress={() => goBack()}
          leftIconContainerStyle={{marginTop:22}}
          leftIconName={'back'}
          leftIconImageStyle={{height:18,width:18}}
        />
```

Its working fine for me, check this expo link i just created

https://snack.expo.io/rkMzuYrE4

Comment: It's still showing white background and white back icon...I just shared updated screenshot.

Comment: You need to use tintColor for the leftIconImageStyle and that will work.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me check below example:

```
<ActionBar
            containerStyle={{height:60,alignSelf: 'center',paddingRight:40}}
            backgroundColor={'#fff'}
            title={'Gallery'}
            titleStyle={styles.pageTitle}
            onLeftPress={() => goBack()}
            leftIconContainerStyle={{marginTop:22}}
            leftIconName={'back'}
            leftIconImageStyle={{tintColor: '#000000'}}
          />
```